# Pulling values from List - Unix Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, grep

I am trying to pull specific vales from a list. My input looks like this:

```
$ cat data.txt

Name: Mike
Age: 20
Date: June 1st
Color: Red

Name: Jon
Age: 22
Date: May 3rd
Color: Blue

Name: Jamie
Age: 18
Date: December 21st
Color: Green

Name: Chris
Age: 24
Date: July 5th
Color: Blue
```

Then I do the following command to pull some data:

```
grep Name data.txt|cut -c6-20 ;  grep Color data.txt|cut -c7-20
```

Which returns:

```
Mike
Jon
Jamie
Chris
Red
Blue
Green
Blue
```

I would like it to return something more like this:

```
Mike:Red
Jon:Blue
Jamie:Green
Chris:Blue
```

And finally I would like to be able to specify if the Color=blue then output:

```
Jon
Chris
```

Any help making this work would be much appreciated. I am very new to bash scripting and have been trying to teach myself through this and other sites.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `grep`. Use `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this.

1st task:

```
awk -F' *: *|\n' -v RS= '{print $2 ":" $8}' data.txt
Mike:Red
Jon:Blue
Jamie:Green
Chris:Blue
```

2nd task:

```
awk -F' *: *|\n' -v RS= -v Color=Blue '$8 == Color{print $2}' data.txt
Jon
Chris
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just what I need. I like to learn what these commands are doing rather than just blindly copying code so I will be reading up more on `awk`.  It seems like a powerful command. Thanks again!

Comment: `-v RS=' sets record separator as null thus giving us each block in single record. `-F' *: *|\n'` sets input field separator as colon surrounded with optional spaces OR a new line. I would strongly suggest going through an awn tutorial.

Comment: @VanCityGuy, awk is much more than a powerful command, it's a whole language, and it's supremely well suited to *certain* tasks. If you process text, you probably want to learn awk. :)

Answer (score 0):

anubhava has, as always, provided a solution that is correct and concise.

But as with everything in unix, there's more than one way to do this.

For posterity, I'll provide a bash-only answer.

Note that neither bash nor awk provides multi-dimensional arrays or objects, so your data structures are a little limited.  In your case, I'm going to assume that the "Name" field is unique amongst records, which means that it can be used sort of like a "primary key".

We can read your input file and populate multiple bash arrays using the key as .. well, the key.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Note that "declare -A", which sets an associative array, requires bash 4.
declare -A Age Date Color

while IFS=': ' read field value; do
  if [ -z "$field" ]; then
    continue
  elif [ "$field" = Name ]; then
    key="$value"
    continue
  fi
  eval $field["\$key"]="\$value"
done < data.txt
```

The result of this is that you'll have a set of arrays whose keys are the names from your data file and whose values are the respective fields following those names.

For the first task:

```
for Name in "${!Color[@]}"; do
  printf "%s:%s\n" "$Name" "${Color[$Name]}"
done
```

For the second task:

```
for Name in "${!Color[@]}"; do
  if [ "${Color[$Name]}" = "Blue" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$Name"
  fi
done
```

Note that the exclamation point in the `"${!Color[@]}"` causes bash to return the list of indices rather than the list of values.  And obviously, an index can be used to access the values.

Obviously, not as concise as awk, but handling this sort of thing in the shell directly can be useful if you need random access to the data in the arrays.